# Serving JS files statically, Including Node Modules in a Node application with Express, and Client vs Server-side programming

Tags: node.js, express, require, node-modules, cloudinary

I'm fairly new at web development and I've been having an issue with requiring certain node modules in my Express application. I need to access certain code, but I'm having difficulty with the the intricacies of Node, and can't for the life of me access node_modules where I need to.

What I'm attempting to do is utilize the Cloudinary video-player from the node_modules that I've installed. I've included path links in the index.html file which is served from htmlRoutes.js, and I've explicitly directed express to statically load these files within the document, but the application does not recognize these paths as valid. I've tried requiring these modules in separate JS files served up from the public folder, but that's also invalid. From what I understand it might be my own confusion of client-side vs server-side programming, but I don't know how to resolve this, nor what resources I should be reading in order to do so.

Any help would be appreciated. Here's what my server looks like:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const baguetteBox = require('baguettebox.js');
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary');
const axios = require("axios");

const app = express();

// Define a port to listen for incoming requests

// Sets an initial port. We"ll use this later in our listener
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8181;

app.use(express.static('public'));
//static routes that attempts to fetch scripts from node_modules without revealing inner directory structure
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/lodash'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/cloudinary'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/cloudinary-core'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/cloudinary-video-player'));


// Sets up the Express app to handle data parsing
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//routes
require("./routes/htmlRoutes.js")(app);
// require("./routes/apiRoutes.js")(app);

  //configure cloudinary api calls
// cloudinary.config({
//   cloud_name: 'name',
//   api_key: 'key',
//   api_secret: 'secret',
//   secure: true
// })

// Start our server so that it can begin listening to client requests.
app.listen(PORT, function() {

  // Log (server-side) when our server has started
  console.log("App listening on: http://localhost:" + PORT);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen node_modules packages served as static files directly, having said that, I will be agnostic with that working.

An alternative way to deal with this issue is to use a bundler such as Webpack and serve it with Express.js

The reason for this is that even being JavaScript, Webpack will compile the code into something interpretable by the browser, something that in many cases you do not find in a package of Node.js

Answer (score 0):

If you need for example lodash, you dont have to access to node_modules/lodash. Just import lodash by declaring:

```
const lodash = require('lodash');
```

And you can now use lodash in the file you declaring lodash.

Comment: If I were to declare lodash in a javascript file separate from the server file but in the same directory, then load that js file into index, would it still work? i've gotten, "required is not defined' before

Comment: just load lodash once more in your file that requires lodash @robodeco

Comment: You need a bundle like webpack.